# Cascading two different flows

Tags: java, cascading

I am trying to link two cascade flows such that one's output should be input to the other flow.

My first flow definition is like this

```
FlowDef flowDef1 = FlowDef.flowDef().setName("firstflow")
            .addSource(pipe1, sourceTap)
            .addSource(pipe2, targetTap)
            .addTailSink(outputPipe1, targetTap1);

FlowConnector flowconnector1 = new LocalFlowConnector();
Flow flow1 = flowconnector1.connect(flowDef1);


FlowDef flowDef2 = FlowDef.flowDef().setName("secondflow")
            .addSource(outputPipe1, targetTap1)
            .addTailSink(outputPipe2, targetPipe2);


FlowConnector flowconnector2 = new LocalFlowConnector();
Flow flow2 = flowconnector2.connect(flowDef1);

CascadeConnector connector = new CascadeConnector();
Cascade cascade = connector.connect(flow2, flow1);
```

When I run this it says pipe has too many heads [pipe1, pipe2]. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library but it seems that you've attached two sources to `flowDef1`.